# Linq select item after if statement

Tags: c#, linq

I've got a list that i want to breakdown to a other list.

So when the if statement is correct the current item has to be added to the new list

```
var newList = oldList.ForEach( x =>
{
    if (condition)
    {
        // select the current item 
    }
})
```

the part of select the current item is the question

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [Where](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.where.aspx):

```
var newList = oldList.Where(x => condition(x));
```

In this version, `newList` will be an object with [lazy](http://www.softwire.com/blog/2012/08/13/dont-be-too-lazy-linqs-lazy-evaluation-gotchas/) evaluation. To make the result concrete, you can additionally evaluate it at once:

```
var newList = oldList.Where(x => condition(x)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

With Where():

```
 var newList = oldList.Where(x => x < 5);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `Where` method with `ToList` in the end:

```
var newList = oldList.Where(x => condition(x)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code example, "x" will be your current item. So all you have to do is actually add it to the other list.

```
if (condition)
{
    newList.Add(x);
}
```